# window on load 1 times

Tags: javascript, jquery

hello i've use javascript window onload on my page, with google map content.

if i move the marker, window onload is active, but it still loading just not 1 more times, i want to make it just 1 times.

here is the code :

```js
function initialize() {
    var latitude =<?php echo $this->input("lat")->getData();?>;
     var longitude =<?php echo $this->input("long")->getData();?>;
    if(latitude == ""){
        latitude = -6.2297465;
        longitude =  106.829518;
    }
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapAgen<?php echo $idUnik;?>'), {
        center: latlng,
        zoom: 11,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latlng,
        map: map,
        title: 'Set lat/lon values for this property',
        icon : 'map-marker-shadow_2.png',
        <?php if($this->editmode) { ?>
        draggable: true
        <?php }else{ ?>
        draggable: false
        <?php } ?>
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function(a) {
        setCookie("latitude", a.latLng.lat().toFixed(4),1);
        setCookie("longitude", a.latLng.lng().toFixed(4),1);

         $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: location.href,
          async : true,
          data: {
            latitude : a.latLng.lat().toFixed(4),
            longitude : a.latLng.lng().toFixed(4)
            },
          success: function(message) {

              window.location.href=window.location.href;

          }
        });
        console.log(a.latLng.lat().toFixed(4));

        function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
            var d = new Date();
            d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
            var expires = "expires="+d.toUTCString();
            document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires;
        }
    });
};
window.onload = initialize();
```

Comment: `window.location.href=window.location.href;` reloads the page - which you are doing on "dragend"

Comment: yes is true, and i think @JaromandaX is not because window onload problem, but it's because this script  window.location.href=window.location.href; , any idea how to make it just load 1 times if i drag the marker ?

Comment: what happens if you **remove** that line?

Comment: if i remove the script, the page not load, and i can't get the long and latitude map location, because if i move the marker, the page is load and i can get the latitude and longtitude marker location. but the problem is the tab it still loading @jaromanda X

Comment: `if i remove the script` - you mean that one single line, right, like I said

Comment: yes @JaromandaX, if i remode this line 'window.location.href=window.location.href;' the page is not load

Comment: the page doesn't load at all - that seems like incorrect information. do you mean the page doesn't **reload** on dragend, right

Comment: so, you **want** the page to reload, but you don't want to fire onload when the page reloads?

Comment: i just need the page reload 1 times @JaromandaX , because my page it still loading if i drag the marker

Comment: could you prevent dragging until window.onload is complete

Comment: The deleted answer is correct that `window.onload = initialize();` really should be `window.onload = initialize;` Even if it did not fix your issue, you should fix that bug.

Answer (score 1):

Possible solution: set a localStorage value to false. Then initialize() can run conditionally only once regardless how many times the window.location.href is loaded, until localStorage/cache is cleared.

Example:

```
if (localStorage.getItem("isLoaded") === null) {
    localStorage.setItem("isLoaded", "0");
}    

function initialize() {

    if (localStorage.getItem("isLoaded") === "0") {
        localStorage.setItem("isLoaded", "1");

        // Rest of the original initialize() code here.
    }
}

window.onload = initialize;
```

https://jsfiddle.net/93hzexvn/3/

Comment: do you understand the problem with `window.onload = initialize();`

Comment: I actually do not understand the problem well at all to be honest - I thought I did, but the responses have confused me more

Comment: @epascarello do you think it failed on the first attempt because window.onload = initialize(); ran the initialize() immediately before load even completed, as a result of the ();  ?  I undeleted my answer just so that I could comment, as I don't have the rep points to ask the question ^^ above.

Comment: I'll just leave my answer up - if there's a better way to handle this, at least I'll learn something when it's solved. Was already reminded about the correct way of the function being passed as a variable rather than being passed AND invoked. Thanks again all, good luck @RizkiFahrizal

Comment: i try to use this code @MissionMike, but the google map is not appears

Comment: @RizkiFahrizal Seems like there's a logic issue: 

1. initialize() needs to be called on load in order to show the map. 
2. on dragend's $.ajax success, the window is reloaded.
3. The map won't reappear unless initialize() is invoked on window reload, but you say you don't want it to be invoked on window load more than the first time.

I don't see how it can work both ways, but I may be missing something. A standalone JSFiddle example without the PHP might be helpful to debug.